Unable to copy source to remote using cmake presets with rsync
First if all I am new to CMakePresets.json.
What I want to achieve - Is it possible to copy source code from windows machine to a remote linux machine (docker in my case) and compile it ?
I have been using rsync but it does not seem to work. At this point I am not even sure if I can achieve this using presets.
Here's what I did: I created a new Visual Studio CMake project and in the CMakePresets.json file, I added following block (I used chat-gpt to generate this configuration).
{
  "name": "linux-debug",
  "displayName": "Linux Debug",
  "generator": "Ninja",
  "binaryDir": "${sourceDir}/build/${presetName}",
  "installDir": "${sourceDir}/install/${presetName}",
  "cacheVariables": {
    "CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE": "Debug",
    "CMAKE_C_COMPILER": "clang",
    "CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER": "clang++",
    "CMAKE_SYSTEM_NAME": "Linux",               // Explicitly set the target system
    "CMAKE_SYSTEM_PROCESSOR": "x86_64",         // Target architecture for Linux
    "CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH": "/usr/local/lib/cmake",
    "CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS": "-g",                    // Ensure appropriate debug flags for Clang
    "CMAKE_C_FLAGS": "-g"
  },
  "environment": {
    "RSYNC_USER": "test",
    "RSYNC_HOST": "localhost",
    "RSYNC_PORT": "22",
    "RSYNC_DEST": "/home/test/${sourceDirName}",
    "CC": "clang",
    "CXX": "clang++"
  },
  "vendor": {
    "microsoft.com/VisualStudioRemoteSettings/CMake/1.0": {
      //"sourceDir": "$env{HOME}/.vs/$ms{projectDirName}",
      "remoteCMakeListsRoot": "/home/test/${sourceDirName}",
      "remoteCopySources": true,
      "remoteCopyBuildRoot": "/home/test/${sourceDirName}/build/linux-debug",
      "remoteCopyMethod": "rsync",
      "remoteCopySourcesMethod": "rsync",
      "remoteCopySourcesOutputVerbosity": "Normal",
      "remoteCopySetup": [
        {
          "RSYNC_USER": "test",
          "RSYNC_HOST": "localhost",
          "RSYNC_PORT": "22",
          "RSYNC_DEST": "/home/test/${sourceDirName}",
          "description": "Copying files to remote Linux machine",
          "command": "rsync",
          "args": [
            "-avz",
            "--delete",
            "--port=22",
            "${sourceDir}/",
            "${RSYNC_USER}@${RSYNC_HOST}:${RSYNC_DEST}"
          ]
        }
      ],
      "remoteConfigureCommand": [
        "/usr/bin/cmake",
        "-B",
        "/home/test/${sourceDirName}/build/linux-debug",
        "-S",
        "/home/test/${sourceDirName}"
      ],
      "remoteBuildCommand": [
        "/usr/bin/cmake",
        "--build",
        "/home/test/${sourceDirName}/build/linux-debug"
      ]
    }
  }
} 

I have gone through some blogs but I am not sure if I can achieve this or if I am missing something! [Ignore some of the duplicated blocks since they were not resolving, I copied rsync related variables into another block].
